# How do I get ECDH keypair in Android 9.0 pie?

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, elliptic-curve, ecdh

I want to get ECDH keypair (Public key and Private key). This method is not working in Android 9.0 pie, because Security provider "BC" , "SC" is removed from this version. I tried below method

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "BC");
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
keyGen.initialize(256, random);
KeyFactory kaif = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", "BC");
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();
```

Following is the key which i got when using "BC" provider with the bove code, EC Private Key S: 30e3def89f6aca7ab4e1e0e0367bf936955339db03a0c32c63a08293066f9423 EC Public Key X: 1675a6b1c8097f651be6f6a555ab9e5da83f03d3082041ae29111609b98594be Y: ed23f9263c6a1e8892d03a0c33ed9d8bfc5886dfe67fb7947457e3ff43baffca

Method 2: Security.insertProviderAt(BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);

When i Add Bouncy castle in gradle and tried initiating like above, the output is follows privateKey = {OpenSSLECPrivateKey@7518} "OpenSSLECPrivateKey{params={ECDSA-Parameters: (256 bit)\n}}" publicKey = {OpenSSLECPublicKey@7519} "Public-Key: (256 bit)\n00000000 04 5c 2c 76 23 09 41 c4 16 e2 99 ea e0 fa ed 16 |.\,v#.A.........|\n00000010 52 ca 91 d2 0c fe 7f c4 94 76 54 9a 3c 49 ab a5 |R........vT.

I need this to be as simple as above in readable format, do i need to do any conversion to get keys in alphanumeric

Comment: *This method is not working...* That is not a useful description of the problem.

Comment: The code works fine for me in Android 9.0.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: I can't get Private key when you set your target SDK version to 28

Comment: Ok, but *can't get...* is not specific enough to diagnose the problem. What specifically happens?

Comment: Private key variable is available, but there is no private key when generating

Comment: What does that mean? What's the value of `privateKey`?

Comment: @JamesKPolk this is the key which i got when using "BC" provider, EC Private Key S: 30e3def89f6aca7ab4e1e0e0367bf936955339db03a0c32c63a08293066f9423

EC Public Key X: 1675a6b1c8097f651be6f6a555ab9e5da83f03d3082041ae29111609b98594be
            Y: ed23f9263c6a1e8892d03a0c33ed9d8bfc5886dfe67fb7947457e3ff43baffca

Comment: Yes. That is the private key.

Comment: when i Add Bouncy castle manually i am getting different keypair, privateKey = {OpenSSLECPrivateKey@7518} "OpenSSLECPrivateKey{params={ECDSA-Parameters: (256 bit)\n}}"
publicKey = {OpenSSLECPublicKey@7519} "Public-Key: (256 bit)\n00000000  04 5c 2c 76 23 09 41 c4  16 e2 99 ea e0 fa ed 16  |.\,v#.A.........|\n00000010  52 ca 91 d2 0c fe 7f c4  94 76 54 9a 3c 49 ab a5  |R........vT.<I..|\n00000020  bc 67 31 ad 93 e4 aa be  8d d2 a0 35 08 e0 d7 0f  |.g1........5....|\n00000030  85 7d 2e 87 91 45 89 e6  1c f8 e2 3f 27 7b 11 55  |.}...E.....?'{.U|\n00000040  ce|.|\n"

Comment: 1) I don't understand what you mean by "add Bouncycastle manually", and 2)  I still don't understand what the problem is. Every time you generate a private key it will be different. It is strange that you get a keypair NOT from Bouncycastle in the second case, but that will require some looking into including duplicating as close as possible your setup.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: 1. Not manually, instead of using in KeypairGenerator instance like this  KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "BC")  i tired to add it like Security.insertProviderAt(BouncyCastleProvider(), this doesn't make any difference in generating keypair  2. Problem description : I need ECDH Keypair, above code is working fine when target sdk is 27 whereas in 28 i was not able to get the keypair

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `SpongyCastle` manually:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);

KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
keyGen.initialize(256, random);
KeyFactory kaif = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();
```

add this to your `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
/* spongy castle */
implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0"
implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0"
```

Make sure the `BouncyCastleProvider()` was coming from `spongycastle`:

`import org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`

Comment: I tried this method, but Public key and Private key seems to be similar

Comment: @DevTamil: That makes no sense.

Comment: Why bother to add spongycastle?

Comment: In my end, I was using ECIES and it works by adding spongycastle. From what I remember, crypto algorithms on higher android versions was stripped down, I'm not sure the exact version though. That's why you need to add it manually.

Comment: All you need to do is take his code, and run it on Android 9. It runs fine without Spongycastle.

Comment: Listen my question carefully @JamesKPolk , I want keypair(private key and public key) which works fine when adding provider "BC" in the lower versions. When i remove Provider in 9.0, Private key is not generated

Comment: @TentenPonce You have discarded my Edit suggestions multiple times. So i have posted the exact answer below. Thanks

Comment: bouncycastle has some package conflicts in android thats why im rejecting it. Does BouncyCastle work for you? Didnt notice youre the OP

Answer (score 1):

Remove Provider ("BC") and insert BouncyCastle Manually

```
Security.removeProvider("BC");
Security.insertProviderAt(BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);

KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
keyGen.initialize(256, random);
KeyFactory kaif = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();
```

add this to your `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
/* Bouncy castle */
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:com.springsource.org.bouncycastle.jce:1.46.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for removing part.
wasted one day to fine this line :p

Answer (score 0):

One could also add `BouncyCastleProvider` alias `bcprov-jdk15on`:

```
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle
    implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.60"
    implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.60"
}
```