# Android Q bouncy castle issue

Tags: android, bouncycastle, spongycastle

From API level 28, Google has restricted Security provider feature(bouncy castle issue).
So alternatively we have added Security provider using spongy castle
Now we can able to generate a keypair. But the key pair is not matching with the previous one. We can't get Private keyThis is we used previously, Old codeapi 27:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "BC");
SecureRandom random =SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
keyGen.initialize(256, random);KeyFactory kaif = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", "BC");
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();
```

After the API level issue, we have removed "BC" and added Bouncy Castle manually by adding the below `lineSecurity.insertProviderAt(BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);`
by implementing Bouncy castle in dependencies,
implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0"
implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0"
But the key pair is not matching with the previous one.
New Code:api 28

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
keyGen.initialize(256, random);
KeyFactory kaif = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();
```

But the key pair is not matching with the previous one.

Image:[image: code]
[image: expectation]

Comment: your question is not clear enough, please read [MCVE] and edit your question accordingly

Comment: ok let me add sample

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get ECDH keypair in Android 9.0 pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884608/how-do-i-get-ecdh-keypair-in-android-9-0-pie)

Comment: Please see this answer for a full example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66323575/215266

Answer (score 0):

try insert new BouncyCastleProvider() on the first row of your security provider and remove all setprovider("BC") from your code.

Comment: Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
            Security.removeProvider("BC");
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            keyGen.initialize(256, random);
            KeyFactory kaif = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
            KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
            PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
            PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();  i already tried this

Comment: but issue exist

Comment: No you should remove "BC" if exist then insert

Comment: Also if you use spongycastle the provider should be "SC" not "BC"

Comment: Hi @frestonic attached images at description please refer

Comment: i'm no expert in generating keys but shouldn't EC have some curve reference?

Comment: KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "BC");
                keyPairGenerator.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp521r1"), new SecureRandom());
                java.security.KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

Comment: in the above code, you can't include providing. The main rule of android p is to remove the provider. The above code throws an exception

Comment: the answer you had posted doesn't seem to related to my query